# Python change dinamically json key

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a specific JSON file that I read and change dynamically the value of key. I'm using this code to do this:

```py
with open('payload/run_job.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data['name'] = 'test'
    result = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)
    pprint(data)
```

and this is my JSON file

```json
{
    "name":"",
    "template": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "name_job": "",
                "env": [
                    {
                        "name": "COUNTRY",
                        "value": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "NAME",
                        "value": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ISTANCE_UUID",
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I have to change also the value of name `ISTANCE_UUID` into array object env. How i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to iterate over containers and then over envs within each container. When you find the given value for the key you seek you can update that env then break out.

Note though, if you control the data format, I would look at altering it so that `env` was a dictionary rather than a list of keys and values.

```py
data = {
    "name":"",
    "template": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "name_job": "",
                "env": [
                    {"name": "COUNTRY", "value": ""},
                    {"name": "NAME", "value": ""},
                    {"name": "ISTANCE_UUID", "value": ""}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

for container in data["template"]["containers"]:
    for env in container["env"]:
        if env["name"] == "ISTANCE_UUID":
            env["value"] = ["some", "list?"]
            break
    else: ## aka no_break
        continue
    break

import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```